# how do i open my class from main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm attempting to open my class Speak2 from my main activity with this snippet:

```
Intent i = new Intent("R.voice.Speak2");
startActivity(i);
```

This is the full code from the first activity:

```
public class recon extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    static final int check = 2000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(recon.this, Speak2.class); 
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

My program is simple. The button appears from voice.xml layout and when pressed launches the class activity Speak2. Why does the second activity never show?

Comment: Java convention is to begin class names with a capital letter. Your "recon" class should be renamed to "Recon" to conform. To go one step further, renaming it to "ReconActivity" would make it especially clear what the class is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way and make sure your `Activity Speak2` is also defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, otherwise you're going to get an exception.

```
// MainActivity is your main activity
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Speak2.class); 
startActivity(i);
```

Your `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` should look like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="recon" >
        <intent-filter > 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Speak2" />
</application>
```

Comment: for manifest file , how ? <action android:name="android.intent.action.Speak2" />

Comment: or <application android:name="com.voice.Speak2" /> ?

Comment: like this `<Activity android:name=".Speak2"/>` inside `<application>`

Comment: 1:25:19.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3088): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.voice.recon/voice.Speak2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: instead of name `"voice.Speak2"` write `".Speak2"`. I edited the answer.

Comment: I added the code for main activity above, perhaps will help... ?